# Incorrect routing in controller using Rails 4 Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm following along with this tutorial (http://www.yoniweisbrod.com/autocomplete-magic-with-rails/) using jQuery-ui's autocomplete, but when I attempt to search using the text field, it routes to the controller's show method instead of the autocomplete_ingredient_name method.

Here's the code for my form:

```
<%= form_tag(cocktail_path(1), :method => 'get', :class => "search_form", :remote => true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:query, "Choose ingredients:") %>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag(:query, params[:query], autocomplete_ingredient_name_cocktails_path, {class: "search-query", placeholder: "", type: "search"}) %>
  <% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "ingredients[]", ingredient.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

And my controller.

```
class CocktailsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :ingredient, :name

  def index
    @cocktails = []
    @ingredients = []
  end

  def autocomplete_ingredient_name
    @ingredients = Ingredient.order(:name).where("name LIKE ?", "'%#{params[:query]}%'")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { 
        render json: @ingredients.map(&:name)
      }
    end
  end

  def show
    hash = {}
    @cocktails = []
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all.map {|ingredient| ingredient}
    @ingredients.select! {|ingredient| ingredient.name.downcase.include?(params[:query])}
    if params[:ingredients] 
      old_ingredients = []
      params[:ingredients].each do |ing|
        old_ingredients << Ingredient.find_by(name: ing)
      end
      cocktails = @ingredients.map {|ingredient| ingredient.cocktails }.flatten
      old_cocktails = old_ingredients.map {|ingredient| @cocktails << ingredient.cocktails }.flatten!
      old_cocktails.each do |cocktail|
        hash[cocktail] = 1
      end
      cocktails.each do |cocktail|
        if hash.has_key?(cocktail)
          @cocktails << cocktail
        end
      end
      @cocktails = @cocktails.uniq.flatten
    else
      @cocktails = @ingredients.map {|ingredient| ingredient.cocktails }.flatten
    end

  end


end
```

And here is the message from my server, going to the CocktailsController#show method, instead of the autocomplete method.

```
Started GET "/cocktails/autocomplete_ingredient_name?term=mi" for ::1 at 2015-10-12 15:32:21 -0500
Started GET "/cocktails/autocomplete_ingredient_name?term=mi" for ::1 at 2015-10-12 15:32:21 -0500
Processing by CocktailsController#show as JSON
Processing by CocktailsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"mi", "id"=>"autocomplete_ingredient_name"}
  Parameters: {"term"=>"mi", "id"=>"autocomplete_ingredient_name"}
  Ingredient Load (8.6ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients"
  Ingredient Load (8.6ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `include?'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `block in show'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `select!'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `show'



TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `include?'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `block in show'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `select!'
  app/controllers/cocktails_controller.rb:25:in `show'
```

The code is supposed to create a jQuery-ui dropdown that predicts what you're searching, but the dropdown never shows up and it immediately returns a 500 error.

Any thoughts on why this isn't routing to the right method would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because of a routing error, i.e. your `GET "/cocktails/autocomplete_ingredient_name?term=mi"` directive is handled by the wrong entry in your /config/routes.rb file.

Make sure the route that handles your autocomplete process is defined prior to the route that handles the show action of your cocktails controller.
Since the latter usually takes the form `get 'cocktails/:id'`, the 'autocomplete_ingredient_name' part of the URI is affected to the `:id` component and the processing is delegated to the `show` action of your controller with said id.

The autocomplete route is defined, since the `autocomplete_ingredient_name_cocktails_path` directive in your form generates a properly formatted URI ; so I believe this is merely an issue of precedence.

You have another potential issue, however: your autocomplete query parameter is 'term' in your request, but it is 'query' in your controller action. They should have the one and same name.

Comment: Yep, that solved it. I just moved that route to the top, and fixed the query/term discrepancy and now it's working. Thanks for your help!